# geom_density: remove horizontal line at zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to remove the horizontal line at zero for `geom_density`? This line looks not so beautiful when trying to plot two overlapping density line at the same time.

The demo example is retrieved from here:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-density-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5),
                 rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
  )

library(ggplot2)
# Basic density
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + geom_density()
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is, you would have to use the density stat function and change the geom to line (optionally the position to `"identity"`):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  stat_density(geom = "line", position = "identity")
```

[image]